# wrapping the json created by Gson with class name

Tags: java, json, gson

In our project is, the models are generated,

what I need to do is change

```
{
"name": "someName",
"model" :" modelID"
}
```

to

```
{
"car":
  {
   "name": "someName",
   "model" :" modelID"
  }
}
```

from my class

```
public class Car {
   private String name;
   private String model;
... getter and setters ...
}
```

Is there some kind of configuration or ... to do this ? I know it is possible with jackson, but we are using Gson
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found 2 ways to do this

1. using GsonFireBuilder

```
Gson gson = new GsonFireBuilder().wrap(Car.class,"Car").createGson();
```

2. 

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement je = gson.toJsonTree(new Car());
JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
jo.add("Car", je);
```